# Google Cloud Storage Python Client Api Buffer Object

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-api-python-client

I am able to upload an image through a Django form to Google Cloud storage.  I want to store the image's content-type data as a string variable and pass this to the `<img>` tag for html display. However, the `.read()` method from this google cloud storage buffer object seems to return nothing?

```
def success(request):

    name = request.session['name']
    content_type = request.session['content_type']

    buffer_object =  gcs.open('/'+bucket_name+'/'+name)

    picture = buffer_object.read()

    stats = gcs.stat('/'+bucket_name+'/'+name)
    return render_to_response('success.html',{'picture':picture,'stats':stats,'mime':content_type,'gcs_file':buffer_object})
```

Comment: How are you outputting the picture in your template?

Comment: I decided to use the blobstore and [create_gs_key()](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/functions) and [get_serving_url()](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/functions) with the Images API as others have mentioned. I had been trying something like <img src="data:{{mime}};base64,{{picture}}"/>,  where mime was the content-type and {{picture}} was the actual string data.  I am still not sure if it was django, python or the google-cloud-storage python client lib. causing the problem.